# How to assign an array of String to definition of mongoose model in post route

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am working on a project on Node.JS and there I created an User Schema which has a property called interests which contain array of String ,while assigning the keys with the  request value the interests key does not take the value of the request property.

POST route:

```
app.post('/users', (req,res) => {
  var user = new Users({
    name : req.body.name,
    email : req.body.email,
    phone : req.body.phone,
    designation : req.body.designation,
    address : req.body.address,
    intrests : req.body.intersts //Here I have added an array of String
  });

  user.save().then((userData) => {
    res.status(200).send(userData);
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  })
});
```

USER Schema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name : {
    type : String,
    required : true,
    trim : true,
    minlength : 5,
    unique : true
  },
  email : {
    type : String,
    required : true,
    trim : true,
    minlength : 5,
    validiate : {
      validator : validator.isEmail,
      message : 'Email is Valid'
    }
  },
  phone : {
    type : Number,
    minlength : 10,
    required : true
  },
  designation : {
    type : String,
    minlength : 4,
    required : true
  },
  address : {
    type: String,
    required : true
  },
  intrests : {
      type : Array,
      default : [],
      required : true
  }
});
```

I have entered following input...

```
{
    "name" : "Surya",
    "email" : "suryanarayan88@outlook.com",
    "phone" : "8895591782",
    "designation" : "Java Developer",
    "address" : "186/1783 Mahadev Nagar",
    "intrests" : ["web developement","Games"]
}
```

I got results as ...

```
{
    "_id": "5d031d27acc9840c7c3997a0",
    "name": "Surya",
    "email": "suryanarayan88@outlook.com",
    "phone": 8895591782,
    "designation": "Java Developer",
    "address": "186/1783 Mahadev Nagar",
    "intrests": [
        null
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Change your interest schema to

`intrests : [String]`

Comment: Tried that also, same output

Comment: what is the console.log of `req.body.intersts`

Comment: ```console.log(req.body.interests); gives ['web development','Games']```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema is wrong for storing array or string

it should be,

```
... // rest of schema code
address : { type: String, required : true},
intrests : {type: Array,  required : true, default : [] }
```

As your previous schema for `interests` was expecting an array of object `[{interest: []}]`

and you were passing `["web developement","Games"]` an array of string.

Note: as per your comment,
This.

```
interests : [{
      type : String,
      default : [],
      required : true
  }]
```

Should be this in your schema.

```
intrests : {type: Array,  required : true, default : [] }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I got the following output with the Schema ```{
    "intrests": [],
    "_id": "5d032e6e2ad2151cf0d1ec8a",
    "name": "SuryaNara",
    "email": "surnarayanr8dd8@outlook.com",
    "phone": 8895591782,
    "designation": "Java Developer",
    "address": "186/1783 Mahadev Nagar",
    "__v": 0
} ```

Comment: Please, can you put your updated schema in question?